# Parametric integral question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I haven't done something like this in a long time. How do I set something like this up? Can someone help me with the beginning or give me some direction?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you remember what a conservative vector field is? Notice that F is the gradient of some other function.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector field is irrotational, i.e., $\nabla \wedge \mathbf{F} = 0 $, and there exists $G$ such that $\nabla G = \mathbf{F}$. We can see that $G = x^2/ 2 + 2 x y + y^2/2$ and [***therefore***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem):

$$ \int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} = G(\mathbf{r}(t=3)) - G(\mathbf{r}(t=0)) $$

Hope you find this helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your vector field is conservative. You can then calculate the  the potential function by finding the integral of F(x,y), in this case V = (1/2)x^2 + (1/2)y^2 + 2xy. Then by plugging in the end point and the beginning point,t = 3 and t = 0 respectively. This leaves us with V(c(3)) - V(c(0)) = V(4,6) - V(1,1) = [8+18+48] - [1/2 + 1/2 + 2] = 71. We can shorthand it with just endpoints because of the the properties of a conservative vector field.